# Set a default image for a PDF thumbnail preview in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I've been working on this for a while and done many Googles but can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. (I've this week taken over a 2-year old site so I'm still trying to find my way around which doesn't help).

When a file is uploaded, a thumbnail preview image is created. For image files, this preview is created no problem, but for PDF's I want to set a default image as the thumbnail, instead of a preview of the PDF.

In my DocumentUploader class I have the following which sets the image thumbnail (I've not included some bits that aren't relevant):

```
def convert_to_image(height, width)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open(current_path)
  image.resize "#{height}x#{width}"
  image.write(current_path)
end

version :preview, if: :not_svg? do
  process convert_to_image: [210, 297]
  process convert: :jpg

  def full_filename(for_file = model.file)
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + ".jpg"
  end
end

def not_svg?(new_file)
  !new_file.content_type.start_with? "image/svg+xml"
  !new_file.content_type.start_with? "application/pdf"
end
```

Using this as a basis, I wrote the following for a PDF (again, the non-relevant parts excluded):

```
def set_default_pdf(height, width)
  image = MiniMagick::Image.open("app/assets/images/pdf_placeholder.svg")
  image.resize "#{height}x#{width}"
  image.write("app/assets/images/pdf_placeholder.svg")
end

version :preview, if: :pdf? do
  process set_default_pdf: [210, 297]
  process convert: :jpg

  def full_filename(for_file = model.file)
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + ".jpg"
  end
end

def pdf?(new_file)
  new_file.content_type.start_with? "application/pdf"
end
```

My view has the following:

```
<%= link_to document.file.url, target: "_blank" do %>
  <%= image_tag document_preview_url(document.file) if document.file? %>
<% end %>
```

So I've followed that to my DocumentPreviewHelper module which has the following:

```
def document_preview_url(file)
  return file.preview.url(response_content_type: %( "image/jpeg" )) if file.preview.present?

  file.url(response_content_type: %( "image/svg+xml"))
end
```

With the comments:

```
  # Retrieve a preview thumbnail for a PDF with the correct content type set.
  #
  # Without overriding the content_type, the headers would return 'application/pdf'
  # for the preview image, and all browsers except for Safari will show the image
  # (regardless of the content type header). This fixes the preview thumbs for Safari.
```

I feel like this is where I should be making my changes, but from my (limited) knowledge it seems to me like the PDF previews should be showing, since they've been converted to jpg in DocumentUploader.

I've tried various different tweaks and changes but the PDF previews just stay as broken links. What am I missing / where am I going wrong? I feel like this should be an easy fix but I'm just not seeing it and frustration is setting in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to create a 'thumbnail_image' method in your ApplicationHelper that takes the document as an argument:

```
def thumbnail_image(document)
  if document.pdf?
    path_to_default_thumbnail (i.e. app/assets/images/thumbnail.jpg)
  else
    document_preview_url(document.file)
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= link_to document.file.url, target: "_blank" do %>
  <%= image_tag thumbnail_image(document.file) if document.file? %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was on the right track so I'm relieved I'm not as much of an idiot as I thought :)